# How to store Token for firebase cloud functions efficiently?

Tags: express, google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

I have a firebase cloud function that uses express middleware to generate an authToken which is passed on up through the routes.

This token lasts 24 hr's so I don't want to spam the service with excessive requests. As such I want to cache the result for a while before regenerating it.

I considered two approaches.

1. See how to cache the axios request when generating the token.
2. Use Firebase Secret Manager to store the value.

Whilst researching the axios caching, I already had secret manager in use so have implemented both in parallel.

**Secret Manager**

Currently I have implemented secret manager to store and update the token, when I need the token for the external API, I can just grab it from secret manager..

I have a scheduled job that then creates a new token, and subsequently disables all prior secret versions before adding in the new token.

Creating the token is achieved by using axios to call the auth end point of the external API.

**Axios Caching**
When it comes to finding out how to enable caching for express running on cloud functions. I'm currently getting the impression that it involves adding in another layer of complexity, such as either a CDN, or Redis solution.

I've also seen intermediate cache solutions such as https://github.com/AlbinoDrought/cachios which looks like it leverages local memory of some sort.  Which I assume would mean that cloud functions distributed across different regions/instances would have there own unique local cache. I wouldn't know if this is a problem or not. But would I think be more lightweight in configuration and setup than say redis?

**My Problem** is, and I hope this isn't too opinion based for SO. but.

Is this use of secret manager a really bad idea. Given secret manager is generally I think geared around long lived values that don't change that often. Or is it perfectly fine, that if I have 2 requests a day, that could be 2x365 versions a year logged against the secret manager, which would have to be tidied up everynow and then. Are the implications I'm not aware of?

Or is enabling some sort of CDN or express caching layer a much more standard approach? And if so is there any guidance on a simple express caching layer that's geared specifically for google Firebase cloud functions?

Comment: Also asked here. 
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Using-Secret-Manager-for-Auth-Tokens/m-p/393884#M222

Comment: your approach is good. You are using secrets manager to store secret and rotating them as needed. How often you are rotating is subjective but if your requirement is to rotate twice a day, you do you. Nothing wrong with the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 requests per day is fine. See the documentation on rotating keys here: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/rotation-recommendations

Note that it suggests, in approach 2 & 3, that valid use cases include grabbing secrets on each launch, and grabbing secrets continuously. 2x/day is less frequent than both of these.

Comment: You know, I could swear I read this page. Whilst it does indeed discuss the frequency of accessing keys, it doesn't quite cover the act of re-generating the secrets. A marginal difference between requesting the key and generating it.  But its definitly worth the bounty so thanks.